# How to pass a user-input string as a field name to access a field within an object?

Tags: c#, linq, system.reflection

I'm doing a little bit of search from a database using linq. I have multiple column names like country, name, phone number...

Now I've created a dropdownlist and pass the user selected data as a parameter "searchedField" to my controller method. Now if I take the input of a "country", I expect the code to be

```
    entries = entries.Where(s => s.country.Contains(searchString));
```

If user selected "name"

```
    entries = entries.Where(s => s.name.Contains(searchString));
```

Excuse me for this rather unreasonable example, since I can always just copy lines and make cases, but I wonder if there is a way to utilize things like reflection to convert string to "code" to access a field?

```
    String searchedField = "name"

    ...

    entries = entries.Where(s => s.searchedField.Contains(searchString));
```

This is my first question here, thanks!

Comment: You'll need reflection for this, and specifically GetMethod(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1(v=vs.110).aspx (you'll also need GetField and GetProperty, if memory serves me well)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# use string as a class field name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179870/c-sharp-use-string-as-a-class-field-name)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq dynamic queries for user search screens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539270/linq-dynamic-queries-for-user-search-screens)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Dynamic Linq](https://www.google.nl/search?q=dynamic%20linq&oq=dynamic%20linq&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1144j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

```
entries = entries
    .Where(
        string.Format(
            "{0} = '{1}'",
            searchedField,
            searchString
        )
    );
```

Note: depending on the type of field you'll need to add quotes, or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a reflection lookup (note: I've omitted error checking):

```
string GetPropertyAsString(object obj, string propertyName)
{
  var propertyInfo - obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
  return propertyInfo.GetValue(obj).ToString();
}
```

and then say

```
entries = entries.Where(s => GetPropertyAsString(s, searchedField).Contains(searchString));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build an expression tree for this (which will work with Linq to entities).

```
public static class QueryableExtensions {
   public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, string propertyName, string searchValue)
        {
            var type = typeof (T);
           //this will be the left part of the lambda
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "s");
            //s.country for example
            var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
            //string.Contains method
            var containsMethod = typeof (string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] {typeof (string)});
            //s.country.Contains(<yoursearchvalue>)
            var expression = Expression.Call(property, containsMethod, Expression.Constant(searchValue));
            //s => s.country.Contains(<yoursearchvalue>)
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, parameter);
            //filter your queryable with predicate
            return queryable.Where(lambda);
        }
}
```

usage

```
var fieldtosearch = "country";
entries = entries.Filter(fieldtosearch , searchString);
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, other than using dynamic linq queries, you could also use Expression to build a generic method to construct a property Getter and use it in your linq query, a quick sampel:

```
    public static Func<TObject, TProperty> GetPropGetter<TObject, TProperty>(string propertyName)
    {
        ParameterExpression paramExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TObject), "value");
        Expression propertyGetterExpression = Expression.Property(paramExpression, propertyName);
        Func<TObject, TProperty> result =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<TObject, TProperty>>(propertyGetterExpression, paramExpression).Compile();
        return result;
    }
```

to use it:

```
        var getter = GetPropGetter<YourEntity, string>("Name");
        var found = entites.Where(m => getter(m).Contains("someInput"));
```